# SQL Trace record history using ID fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier, recursive-query

Firstly I apologize if the subject of this question is not clear or is using the wrong terminology, but I'm not quite sure what I am trying to do is called. I am using SQL Server 2016. I have a table which has the following three columns:

```
create table #temp (PrevID varchar(10),ID varchar(10), NextID varchar(10))
insert into #temp
Select NULL,'ABC1','ABC3' Union all
Select NULL,'ABC2','ABC4' Union all
Select 'ABC1','ABC3','ABC9' Union all
Select 'ABC2','ABC4','ABC10' Union all
Select 'ABC3','ABC9',NULL Union all
Select 'ABC4','ABC10','ABC25' Union all
Select 'ABC10','ABC25',NULL

PrevID |ID   | NextID
NULL   |ABC1 | ABC3
NULL   |ABC2 | ABC4
ABC1   |ABC3 | ABC9
ABC2   |ABC4 | ABC10
ABC3   |ABC9 | NULL
ABC4   |ABC10| ABC25
ABC10  |ABC25| NULL
```

What i am looking to do is get an output of the the ID's which are related to each other. I cannot simply sort by ID in ascending order because ABC1 and ABC2 are part of two different chains, and while each chain is sequential they are not continuous.

Normally I would use a CTE or subquery to join the table against itself to be able to query against the next or previous records, however there is no specific limit to how many records will be part of a chain and so I cannot know in advance the number of times I would need to rejoin join the table. Unfortunately I am also unable to change the structure of the table to get a ChainID added.

The desired output would be something like the below:

```
ChainID|PrevID |ID   | NextID
Chain1 |NULL   |ABC1 | ABC3
Chain1 |ABC1   |ABC3 | ABC9
Chain1 |ABC3   |ABC9 | NULL

Chain2 |NULL   |ABC2 | ABC4
Chain2 |ABC2   |ABC4 | ABC10
Chain2 |ABC4   |ABC10| ABC25
Chain2 |ABC10  |ABC25| NULL
```

Thanks and I appreciate any help

-- Edited to include code i used to create table for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a graph walking problem.  The following should get the minimum id for each connected group.

```
with edges as (
      select distinct v.id1, v.id2
      from t cross apply
           (values (prev_id, id), (id, prev_id), (next_id, id), (id, next_id)
           ) v(id1, id2)
      where id1 is not null and id2 is not null
     ),
     cte as (
      select id1, id1 as id2, 
             convert(varchar(max), concat(',', id1, ',')) as ids
      from edges
      union all
      select cte.id1, e.id2,
             concat(ids, e.id2 + ',')
      from cte join
           edges e 
           on cte.id2 = e.id1
      where cte.ids not like concat('%,', e.id2, ',%')
     )
select id1, min(id2) as grp, dense_rank() over (order by min(id2)) as grp_num
from cte
group by id1;
```

You can then `join` back to the original data to assign the group to the original rows.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0dbde41958618c15301dd49b36148e86) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. unfortunately I get an error invalid column name id2. i changed the "t" to #temp and removed the "_" but made no other changes. I also need to apply the group number to all records not just the first. I can get the originals easily enough by using "Where PrevID is null" since only original records will have null in this field, but I need to identify all records in a chain.

Comment: @Ben . . . I'm not to the point yet where I can hammer these out without testing.  So, I made a couple small changes and included a link to a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. i was able to get this to work with my test dataset, run-time seems to deteriorate very quickly as the dataset size goes up though. Using a sample size of ~700 rows from my actual data-table the query runs well over 5 min. Any ideas to speed this up?

Comment: @Ben . . . A recursive CTE is not going to be a good approach on a fair amount of data with largish components.  Every edge needs to be generated.  It might help to save `edges` as a temporary table, so it is not recalculated on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff for pointing me in the right direction with graph walking which lead me to this post on recursive queries [SQL SERVER – Introduction to Hierarchical Query using a Recursive CTE – A Primer](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/)

I realized that I don't really need to look in both directions for every record to get the history of records, since every record will have a "NextID" until the last which will be NULL I can just follow it forward from the base record.  I came up with the below query which completes my ~700 row sample test in just under a second.

```
create table #temp (PrevID varchar(10),ID varchar(10), NextID varchar(10))
insert into #temp 
Select NULL,'ABC1','ABC3' Union all
Select NULL,'ABC2','ABC4' Union all
Select 'ABC1','ABC3','ABC9' Union all
Select 'ABC2','ABC4','ABC10' Union all
Select 'ABC3','ABC9',NULL Union all
Select 'ABC4','ABC10','ABC25' Union all
Select 'ABC10','ABC25',NULL

;

with descendants as
      ( select id as ParentID, nextid as ChildID, 2 as rn
          from #temp 
     union all
        select d.ParentID, s.nextid, d.rn + 1
          from descendants as d
          join #temp s on d.ChildID = s.id
      ) 
    select *
      from descendants a
     where not exists 
            (select distinct d.ChildID
               from descendants d
              where d.ChildID = a.ParentID)
       and ChildID is not null
 union all
    select id,id, 1 
      from #temp t
     where t.previd is null

order by 1,3
```